Why are my unit tests failing to assert the TextField values in my ReactPWA?
I have a React PWA and I'm using Material UI form.
"@mui/icons-material": "^6.1.4",
"@mui/lab": "^6.0.0-beta.12",
"@mui/material": "^6.1.4",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
I have a simple test I've tried to alter different ways to get it to pass. The following test fails with the following error:
Expected the element to have form values
- Expected
+ Received

  Object {
-   "drinkingHabits": "Never",
-   "education": "Other",
+   "drinkingHabits": "",
+   "education": "",
    "email": "test@example.com",
-   "gender": "Female",
+   "gender": "",
    "password": "1234567890",
-   "smokingHabits": "Occasionally",
+   "smokingHabits": "",
    "userBio": "this is my bio",
    "username": "username",
  }

I've tried several different ways to make this work and here is my last attempt:
The unit test:


  test("Button was called with form values", async () => {
    render(
      <AlertProvider>
        <MemoryRouter>
          <RegisterForm />
        </MemoryRouter>
      </AlertProvider>
    );

    //Arrange
    const emailElement = screen.getByPlaceholderText("*Email");
    const passwordElement = screen.getByPlaceholderText("*Password");
    const submit = screen.getByTestId("register-button");
    const bio = screen.getByLabelText("User Bio");
    const dob = screen.getByLabelText("*Date of birth");
    const gender = screen.getByLabelText("*Gender");
    const education = screen.getByLabelText("*Education Level");
    const drinking = screen.getByLabelText("*Drinking Frequency");
    const smoking = screen.getByLabelText("*Smoking Frequency");
    const username = screen.getByPlaceholderText("*Username");

    //Act
    userEvent.type(emailElement, "test@example.com");
    userEvent.type(passwordElement, "1234567890");
    userEvent.type(bio, "this is my bio");
    userEvent.type(username, "username");
    userEvent.type(
      dob,
      new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 18))
        .toISOString()
        .split("T")[0]
    );

    userEvent.type(gender, "Female");
    userEvent.type(education, "Other");
    userEvent.type(drinking, "Never");
    userEvent.type(smoking, "Occasionally");
    fireEvent.click(submit);

    // Assert
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByTestId("reg-form")).toHaveFormValues({
        email: "test@example.com",
        password: "1234567890",
        username: "username",
        userBio: "this is my bio",
        gender: "Female",
        education: "Other",
        drinkingHabits: "Never",
        smokingHabits: "Occasionally",
      });
    });
  });



Here's the form component


import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { DevTool } from "@hookform/devtools";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import {
  CONFIRM_PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER,
  EDUCATION_OPTIONS,
  EMAIL_INVALID,
  EMAIL_PLACEHOLDER,
  EMAIL_REQUIRED,
  FREQUENCY,
  GENDER_OPTIONS,
  PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER,
  PASSWORD_REQUIRED,
  PASSWORD_VALIDATION,
  USERNAME_INVALID,
  USERNAME_PLACEHOLDER,
  USERNAME_REQUIRED,
} from "../shared-strings/constants";
import { Box, Button, Input, MenuItem, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { isUserOver18 } from "../utilities/DateChecker";
import { AlertContext } from "../../Context/AlertContext";

export const RegisterForm = () => {
  type FormValues = {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    username: string;
    userBio: string;
    dob: Date;
    gender: string;
    education: string;
    drinkingHabits: string;
    smokingHabits: string;
    confirmPassword: string;
  };
  const { showAlert } = useContext(AlertContext);
  const [smoking, setSmoking] = useState("");
  const [drinking, setDrinking] = useState("");
  const [edu, setEdu] = useState("");
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = (data: FormValues) => {
    if (data.password !== data.confirmPassword) {
      showAlert("Error", "Passwords do not match.");
      return;
    } else if (!isUserOver18(data.dob)) {
      console.log("Submitted", data.dob);
      showAlert("Error", "Users must be 18 or older.");
    } else if (formState.isValid) {
      console.log("Submitted", data);
    }
  };

  const form = useForm<FormValues>();
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState, setValue } = form;
  const { errors } = formState;

  return (
    <div className="authFormContainer">
      <form
        className="registerForm"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        noValidate
        data-testid="reg-form">
        <Box>
          <Input
            type="text"
            id="username"
            sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 300, mx: "auto" }}
            placeholder={USERNAME_PLACEHOLDER}
            {...register("username", {
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: USERNAME_REQUIRED,
              },
              minLength: {
                value: 4,
                message: USERNAME_INVALID,
              },
            })}
          />
          <p className="error" data-testid="emailErr">
            {errors.username?.message}
          </p>
        </Box>
        <Box>
          <Input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 300, mx: "auto" }}
            placeholder={EMAIL_PLACEHOLDER}
            {...register("email", {
              pattern: {
                value:
                  /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/,
                message: EMAIL_INVALID,
              },
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: EMAIL_REQUIRED,
              },
            })}
          />
          <p className="error" data-testid="emailErr">
            {errors.email?.message}
          </p>
        </Box>
        <Box>
          <Input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            data-testid="password"
            sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 300, mx: "auto" }}
            placeholder={PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER}
            {...register("password", {
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: PASSWORD_REQUIRED,
              },
              minLength: {
                value: 10,
                message: PASSWORD_VALIDATION,
              },
            })}
          />
          <p className="error">{errors.password?.message}</p>
        </Box>
        <Box>
          <Input
            id="confirmPassword"
            data-testid="confirm"
            sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 300, mx: "auto" }}
            placeholder={CONFIRM_PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER}
            {...register("confirmPassword", {
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: PASSWORD_REQUIRED,
              },
              minLength: {
                value: 10,
                message: PASSWORD_VALIDATION,
              },
            })}
          />
          <p className="error">{errors.password?.message}</p>
        </Box>
        <Box mt={2}>
          <TextField
            sx={{ paddingTop: 5 }}
            InputLabelProps={{ style: { color: "white" } }}
            id="userBio"
            label="User Bio"
            multiline
            rows={4}
            placeholder="Tell us about yourself"
            {...register("userBio", {
              maxLength: {
                value: 200,
                message: "Bio should not exceed 200 characters",
              },
            })}
          />
          <p className="error">{errors.userBio?.message}</p>
        </Box>
        <Box>
          <TextField
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
            label="*Date of birth"
            type="date"
            id="dob"
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              maxWidth: 300,
              mx: "auto",
              backgroundColor: "white",
            }}
            {...register("dob", {
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: "Date of birth is required",
              },
            })}
          />
          <p className="error">{errors.dob?.message}</p>
        </Box>
        <Box>
          <TextField
            select
            label="*Gender"
            id="gender"
            value={gender}
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              maxWidth: 300,
              mx: "auto",
              backgroundColor: "white",
            }}
            {...register("gender", {
              onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setGender(e.target.value);
              },
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: "Gender is required",
              },
            })}>
            {GENDER_OPTIONS.map((option, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={index} value={option}>
                {option}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
          <p className="error">{errors.gender?.message}</p>
        </Box>
        <Box>
          <TextField
            select
            label="*Education Level"
            id="education"
            value={edu}
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              maxWidth: 300,
              mx: "auto",
              backgroundColor: "white",
            }}
            {...register("education", {
              onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                console.log("Education Level selected:", e.target.value);
                setEdu(e.target.value);
              },
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: "Education level is required",
              },
            })}>
            {EDUCATION_OPTIONS.map((option, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={index} value={option}>
                {option}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
          <p className="error">{errors.education?.message}</p>
        </Box>
        <Box>
          <TextField
            select
            label="*Drinking Frequency"
            id="drinkingHabits"
            value={drinking}
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              maxWidth: 300,
              mx: "auto",
              backgroundColor: "white",
            }}
            {...register("drinkingHabits", {
              onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setDrinking(e.target.value);
              },
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: "Required",
              },
            })}>
            {FREQUENCY.map((option, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={index} value={option}>
                {option}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
          <p className="error">{errors.drinkingHabits?.message}</p>
        </Box>
        <Box>
          <TextField
            select
            label="*Smoking Frequency"
            id="smokingHabits"
            value={smoking}
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              maxWidth: 300,
              mx: "auto",
              backgroundColor: "white",
            }}
            {...register("smokingHabits", {
              required: {
                value: true,
                message: "Required",
              },
              onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setSmoking(e.target.value);
              },
            })}>
            {FREQUENCY.map((option, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={index} value={option}>
                {option}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
          <p className="error">{errors.smokingHabits?.message}</p>
        </Box>
        <div>
          <p style={{ color: "white" }}>
            Already have an account? <Link to="/">Sign in</Link>
          </p>
        </div>
        <Button type="submit" data-testid="register-button" variant="contained">
          Register
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};




When you provide this prop to TextField like so:
data-testid="email"

Mui will add it to one of its containing elements (that it uses for styling purposes) that represents the TextField, which won't have a value property on its HTML element reference as it will likely be some <div>.
Provide this instead:
inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'email' }}

And repeat for the password field. This will put the data-testid attribute on the actual underlying <input> HTML element, which will have the value.
The code where you log event.target.elements.email.value is not equivalent to the test code, as this gets the values via the form HTML element elements API, which already resolves any containing form field element like <input> automatically (indexing them via it's name attribute), no matter where it is in the child hierarchy.
You could alternatively use toHaveFormValues from testing-library/jest-dom and move forward with that concept in the actual test. In this solution the data-testid and associated assertion would be on the <form> and none would be needed on the fields themselves.
Also, I'm not sure if this is related, but you probably also want to check this before submitting since submit redirects to another page, and those HTML references for the fields you hold in the test may no longer exist in the page (stale). But this is guesswork as I'm not fully sure on intentions.

So I think the problem is that I'm not setting the value of the actual field in the code.  so value={userInput}.  When I hardcode the value <TextField
value="some value", the unit test fails the test but I can see from the error that it's failing it with the hardcoded value.  I need to be able to set the value programmatically in the field from the user input but not sure how.  This was the suggestion that did not work value={form.watch("email")}

Ah I neglected to mention that in my answer, but indeed, the above will fix that too. THe problem is the test id is not on the <input> HTML element itself. The <TextField> component is a deeply nested structure and your testid is not on the input within. My answer will fix that, without a change to the test code. You simply need to move the data-testid attributes into inputProps as above. At the moment yes, the type() will be applied to a wrapping div and not the input, which wont work as you describe. Please give this a go as likely your problem will instantly vanish.

I think the confusion you have is around that because <TextField> has a value prop, you are assuming the test code has to set that value prop. This is incorrect. react-testing-library operates on the DOM layer that is produced from the react components. It can not introspect or interact with the  value prop directly. It can only interact with DOM elements. I.e. type in the <input>. What you want to set is the value object property of the HTML element reference for the <input>, and that will be fixed when you target the right element by moving the testid as described.

This will of course eventuate a change in the value prop to <TextField> by way of producing key press events on the DOM element, just as a user would. Those are then handled in your application code, as they would be for a user. Trying to change the value prop of TextField to fix this issue is a dead end, and I can see where your mental model has (understandably) slipped into the wrong way of thinking because of the overlapping yet distinct semantics of the meaning of value between the react component prop and the underlying HTML reference.

Its worth noting this is distinct from older test frameworks like enzyme or internal libs like react-dom/test-utils, which do indeed have private backdoor access to the runtime react components and their props. But generally, the community has moved to react-testing-library primarily because it disallows this and forces you to interact with the component as a user would -- which is via the DOM (underlying HTML elements). This is a fundamental difference, and may be confusing when looking at examples online if you don't understand the difference at first.

You can also go on for quite a bit not even realising this until you reach a case like yours. If the mui TextField component passed the spare data attrs directly to the underlying input, you wouldn't even notice. A lot of components do things like this. But here, it does not. It assigns that test id attribute to a root <div> that wraps the <input>. You can see this here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/TextField/TextField.js#L241. So tweaks are needed to get that attr into the right place since you cant type in a <div>, nor does it have a value.

I added your changes by removing the test id from all of the components.  For some reason I still can't get the value of the TextFields in order to pass the test.  It works when I test manually.  If I set debugger on the onChanged event I can see the value change in the console.  I can also see the form data printed in the console also.  It's not making sense why the test is failing.  As you can see the value from the Input elements are showing, it's only the TextFields.  I tried changing the TextFeild types to Input and Select to no avail.

Can I just confirm you also at the same time as removing the data attrs from the <TextField> at the top level (very important) added inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'email' }} etc on the textfields. as this is critical

why would I need the inputProps{{}}?  I'm using the label to identify the DOM elements for the unit tests?

What I've noticed is if I add this prop then I get a value in the unit tests but it always gives me the first value of the array:           slotProps={{
select: {
native: true,
},
}}
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/

I also get this console error:
The label's for attribute refers to a form field by its name, not its id. This might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form and accessibility tools from working correctly.
To fix this issue, refer to form fields by their id attribute.

"why would I need the inputProps{{}}? I'm using the label to identify the DOM elements for the unit tests?". No you are not, you are passing a prop to a component. And the component in question, in this instance, does not route that to the underlying HTML <input> dom element. No offense intended, but its quite hard to help as I have given the solution, but there is no indication you have applied it.
